# Proof: limit of one fo the bounds is the just the integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ (real numbers) be Riemann-integrable. Prove that

$$\lim_{p \to  b} \int_{a}^{p} f(x) \: dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \: dx$$ and $$\lim_{p \to  a} \int_{p}^{b} f(x) \: dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \: dx.$$

I am so lost with this proof. I assume this is like a prelude to improper integrals, which def hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: Please use [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Let $M=\sup |f|$. Observe that 
$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx-\int_p^bf(x)dx\right|=\left|\int_a^pf(x)dx\right|\le\int_a^p|f(x)|d(x)\le M(p-a)\to 0$$
as $p\to a$

Comment: You also need a bound from below.